# TouchEnd & MouseUp

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, debugging, ionic-framework

Why do both events, TouchEnd and MouseUp, get fired when using a mobile device?

For debugging purposes we run the app in the browser and on mobile devices thats why we need TouchEnd & MouseUp.

The problem is that if I build the app and use it on my iPhone via XCode, both events get fired.

The questions is, is the App built in Safari on my iPhone (which should trigger both events) or do always both events get triggered?

Comment: you can wrap any of them to platform specific logic. like `if(Capacitor.getPlatform() =='web' ) {//do something here for web only}`

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

Refer to these two articles for more information:

[Touch events - Interaction with Mouse Events and click](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#mouse-events) on w3c

[Handling Clicks with touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#handling_click) on MDN